# What the Schuko?

Tags: power-supply, switch-mode-power-supply

I purchased a welder for use in the US. It came with a Schuko cord end. A bit confused on rewire and cannot find any schematics or pictures describing how this circuit travels exactly. I'm very visual so blah blah blah doesn't do me much good.

Welder on all other websites claim it is both 110 and 220. Mine however states 220 input on unit.

Comment: What kind of plug are you planning on wiring the ex-Schuko cord to? A stove plug? This question might be better suited to the DIY SE..

Comment: Talking of visual, the manual may help as it will usually show the plug configuration and how to set for 110 or 220 if that is possible.

Comment: If you want help, you need to give us the manufacturer name and the model of the welder.  A link to the manual would be good, along with a photo of the name plate of the welder.

Comment: Contact OEM to modify to 120V if you got the wrong supply, otherwise change cordset.

Comment: Whoever called it that?.....